# How to cite a website/manual where the authors are (mostly) unknown?

Tags: citations, citation-style, website, latex, bibtex

For my thesis, I need to cite some pieces of software documentation. The website in question is the [documentation of Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/).

I'm fine with using `@misc` entries in my bibtex file, but obviously I need to fill in the author field.

Usually, when I can't find the author of a specific website, I look up the imprint at the bottom of the page. As the Kubernetes documentation doesn't provide any imprint, there is only `© 2017 The Kubernetes Authors` or `Copyright © 2017 The Linux Foundation®` at the bottom of the page.

To me, it looks a little bit odd to have "The Kubernetes Authors" in my bibliography. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

You can cite using @misc without Author field. To to that, you need to include a **key** field. Here is an example:

`@misc{KubernetesManual2017,
    title = {{Kubernetes Manual}},
    howpublished = "\url{please put the url}",
    year = {2017}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Dec-2017]",
    key = "KubernetesManual2017",
}`

Comment: With this solution, the bibtex entry appears without an author in the bibliography. Is this really the academic way? Obviously, someone must have written the documentation.

Comment: If a document has authors, obviously we should mention them. However, if a document doesn't mention any author then possibly it was meant to be that way.